# Reading value of cookie using curl in php

Tags: php, cookies, curl

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [how to get the cookies from a php curl into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895786/how-to-get-the-cookies-from-a-php-curl-into-a-variable)
>   [Any way to keep curl’s cookies in memory and not on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486099/any-way-to-keep-curls-cookies-in-memory-and-not-on-disk)

Hello,

Im using Firefox 3.5.9. When i visit a url , it sets a cookie on my computer.I can see this cookie in Firefox by going to Tools->Options->Privacy,then clicking on 'Remove Individual Cookies'. There is a folder called xyz,which contains a cookie named JSessionId and which has some Content value .
If i use curl in my php code to navigate to that website,is there a way i can read the Content value of that cookie programmatically ? . 
Some sample code would be really appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to SO. This seems to have been asked before, I'll post some links.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895786/how-to-get-the-cookies-from-a-php-curl-into-a-variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486099/any-way-to-keep-curls-cookies-in-memory-and-not-on-disk